# Command line bash for entering multiple directories and executing a command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, do-loops

I'm new to this site (and to programming, more or less), but I'm hoping you can help.

I have numerous directories named 3K, 4K, 5K, etc. Within each directory I have 12 subdirectories named v1 to v12, each containing a file called OUTCAR. I am trying to write a bash command that will allow me to enter each of the subdirectories and gather data from OUTCAR.

The function works with no issues when I enter each subdirectory individually.

I'm using

> for file in v{1..12} ; do grep "key_string" OUTCAR | awk '{print(relevant_stuff)}' > output.dat ; done

From the *K fine that contains the v{1..12} subdirectories.

However, I'm getting an error telling me that OUTCAR doesn't exist for each v{1..12}. I know it does, so I'm guessing that I haven't properly directed the command to cd into each subdirectory first. Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Should all the output go into one output.dat file or do you want an output.dat file beside each OUTCAR file? Overall, it's probably easier to use a find command like: "find -name OUTCAR" and either do the grepping/awking via xargs or iterate the result with a "while read" loop.

Comment: I am aiming to produce a separate output.dat file for each OUTCAR, printed into each v1 to v12 subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better of using this `find` command from top level directory where these sub directories exist:

```
find . -type d -name 'v[1-9][[1-9]' \
    -exec awk '/key_string/ {print FILENAME ":" $0}' {}/* >> output.dat \;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Could you clarify -type and -name for me?

Comment: You can get details from `man find`. `-type d` only finds directories and `-name` matches a pattern agains directory names.